# Adding softmax layer to LSTM network "freezes" output

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, softmax

I've been trying to teach myself the basics of RNN's with a personnal project on PyTorch. I want to produce a simple network that is able to predict the next character in a sequence (idea mainly from this article http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/ but I wanted to do most of the stuff myself).

My idea is this : I take a batch of *B* input sequences of size *n* (np array of *n* integers), one hot encode them and pass them through my network composed of several LSTM layers, one fully connected layers and one softmax unit.
I then compare the output to the target sequences which are the input sequences shifted one step ahead.

My issue is that when I include the softmax layer, the output is the same every single epoch for every single batch. When I don't include it, the network seems to learn appropriately. I can't figure out what's wrong.

My implementation is the following :

```
class Model(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, one_hot_length, dropout_prob, num_units, num_layers):
    
    super().__init__()

    self.LSTM = nn.LSTM(one_hot_length, num_units, num_layers, batch_first = True, dropout = dropout_prob)
    
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_prob)
    self.fully_connected = nn.Linear(num_units, one_hot_length)
    self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim = 1)
    # dim = 1 as the tensor is of shape (batch_size*seq_length, one_hot_length) when entering the softmax unit

def forward_pass(self, input_seq, hc_states):

    output, hc_states = self.LSTM (input_seq, hc_states)
    output = output.view(-1, self.num_units)
    output = self.fully_connected(output) 
    # I simply comment out the next line when I run the network without the softmax layer
    output = self.softmax(output)
    return output, hc_states
```

*one_hot_length* is the size of my character dictionnary (~200, also the size of a one hot encoded vector)
*num_units* is the number of hidden units in a LSTM cell, *num_layers* the number of LSTM layers in the network.

The inside of the training loop (simplified) goes as follows :

```
input, target = next_batches(data, batch_pointer)

input = nn.functional.one_hot(input_seq, num_classes = one_hot_length).float().

for state in hc_states:
    state.detach_()
            
optimizer.zero_grad()
            
output, states = net.forward_pass(input, hc_states)

loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(output, target)
loss.backward()
    
nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(net.parameters(), MaxGradNorm)

optimizer.step()
```

With *hc_states* a tuple with the hidden states tensor and the cell states tensor, *input*, is a tensor of size (*B*,*n*,*one_hot_length*), *target* is (*B*,*n*).

I'm training on a really small dataset (sentences in a .txt of ~400Ko) just to tune my code, and did 4 different runs with different parameters and each time the outcome was the same : the network doesn't learn at all when it has the softmax layer, and trains somewhat appropriately without.
I don't think it is an issue with tensors shapes as I'm almost sure I checked everything.

My understanding of my problem is that I'm trying to do classification, and that the usual is to put a softmax unit at the end to get "probabilities" of each character to appear, but clearly this isn't right.

Any ideas to help me ?
I'm also fairly new to Pytorch and RNN so I apologize in advance if my architecture/implementation is some kind of monstrosity to a knowledgeable person. Feel free to correct me and thanks in advance.

Comment: I was confused by `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` at first too. It does logSoftmax and negative log likelihood loss at the same time, so the softmax is redundant. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss

Comment: Oh ok thank you, I guess I shoudl've read the documentation more thoroughly. I guess I don't need it on my forward pass. However I still don't fully understand it, because when I print the output of my forward pass (so before I compute the loss) I can clearly see that the output is the same. Do you have any idea why adding a softmax layer after the FC one would cause such an issue ? Thank you very much either way